# manytomany field not working django-cms

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-cms

I am using django-cms
many to many field is working fine when i add plugins or update but 
after publish page i didn't get any data where i add many to many field.

models are look like this

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class ClientLogo(CMSPlugin):
  client_logo = models.ManyToManyField(LogoPluginModel, blank=True)

class LogoPluginModel(CMSPlugin):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

here field 'client_logo' will be disapper when i publish djagno-cms page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django cms plugin instance related\_set returns empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778911/django-cms-plugin-instance-related-set-returns-empty-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relations need to be explicitly copied through the `copy_relations` method (see [django-cms models manual](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.3.x/reference/models.html)). It's also advantageous to add a `related_name` property to the ManyToManyField, especially when a model contains multiple sets of foreign keys or `ManyToManyFields`.

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class ClientLogo(CMSPlugin):
  client_logo = models.ManyToManyField(
    LogoPluginModel,
    blank=True,
    related_name='client_logos',
  )


class LogoPluginModel(CMSPlugin):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

  def copy_relations(self, oldinstance):
    self.client_logos.all().delete()
    for logo in oldinstance.client_logos.all():
      logo.pk = None
      logo.showroom = self
      logo.save()
```